# var = true won't pass to another function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, if-statement

I've got a contact field on my website, and tests whether the value inserted is good or not. That part works fine. If a value is right, there is a var made with value = true.

I'm also calling a second function, which tests if all the contacts fields have got a true. If so, the send button will be abled, otherwise it keeps disabled. Sadly enough I get an error in my console, which says: *Uncaught ReferenceError: nameIsGoed is not defined*. 
Hope you can help me out! :)

One of the tree functions which are quietly the same

```
function checkEmptyMessage(field) {
if (field.value != '') {
    document.getElementById("message").style.borderColor="#91bc1e";
    var messageIsGoed = true;
}
else if (field.value == ''){
    document.getElementById("message").style.borderColor="#f15a24";
    var messageIsGoed = false;
}}
```

The function that checks whether the value is true or not, if so: disable get's false.

```
 function checkDisable(){
    if ((nameIsGoed == true) && (messageIsGoed == true) && (mailIsGoed == true)){
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled=false;
        alert("mooizo");
    }
    else{
        alert("er missen nog gegevens");
    }

}
```

Comment: You want to read up on what the `var` keyword inside a function means …

Comment: You should read about scopes. [var - JavaScript - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a scope problem, `var messageIsGoed;`  should be (declared) outside your function, so the value you give it is available to other functions.

```
var messageIsGoed; // outside the function

function checkEmptyMessage(field) {
if (field.value != '') {
    document.getElementById("message").style.borderColor="#91bc1e";
    messageIsGoed = true;
}
else if (field.value == ''){
    document.getElementById("message").style.borderColor="#f15a24";
    messageIsGoed = false;
}}
```

I added (declared) `var messageIsGoed;` outside the function and removed the `var` inside the function so you don't declare it again (which actually makes a new variable only available inside that function).

Read more here about declaring variables: [**MDN**:var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Comment: Fixed the problem, thanks for your reply! After a summer holiday I forgot about the scopes ;)

Comment: @Menno, you're welcome. Nice sometimes to have different people looking to code.

Answer (score 2):

You cant use messageIsGoed outside of function if you declared it using var.
Just declare it outside both functions and use it inside without var so it will be global.

Answer (score 1):

That's a *local* variable.
It only exists inside the function it's declared in.

You want to make a global variable, which will exist everywhere.
Declare the variable outside the function.

Comment: maybe you can share with him how to do that